# c# winform cool colordialog

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, color-picker

I'm working on winforms with .net 4.0 and I need to let the user to choose a color.
The default colorpicker is very ugly.. does anybody knows someone cool for winforms??

googling i've found only for wpf forms, a cool is this:

[extended wpf controls](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=ColorPicker&referringTitle=Home), but is for wpf...

I wish a simple circle with the colors, like photoshop..

in my mind I wish also something like this:

[image]

or better this:

[image]

thanks in advance!

Comment: Creating the first example in winform shouldn't be that hard. But I agree, better not inventing the wheel and end up with funny bugs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can still use the WPF one which you could host as a control within a windows form. The WPF/Winforms integration is pretty cool : You can read more about it over here (at my blog actually) : http://sachabarbs.wordpress.com/2008/02/26/winforms-wpf-interop/

You may need to jiggle the WPF color picker a little to expose a property for color which is accessable from the hosting winforms form, which you would show as a dialog

Answer (score 3):

You can take a look at `DevExpress`' `ColorEdit` [here](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#windowsforms/clsDevExpressXtraEditorsColorEdittopic)

Comment: They used to offer a free basic controls some time ago for a short period of time. I'm not sure if they will still do that in the future though.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for something similar to the first screenshot of the question. The one I found on [codeproject](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9959/Adobe-Color-Picker-Clone-Part-1) looks exact what you are looking for. It is based on WinForms and has almost all required controls within.

[image: Screenshot - Color Picker WinForms]